# Creating function to replace string query slows down the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetYearsByMake] 
    @Make VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT DISTINCT [year] 
   FROM make_model 
   WHERE active = 1 
     AND isUnique = 1 
     AND [dbo].[ReplaceUrlEscapeChars](make) = @Make 
   ORDER BY [year] DESC
END
```

and ReplaceUrlEscapeChars is function which I had created to replace the data containing special character to single -

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReplaceUrlEscapeChars] 
    (@MyString AS VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@MyString LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z\s-]%')
    BEGIN
        SET @MyString = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
            (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(@MyString,'<','-'),'>','-'),'#','-'),'{','-'),'}','-'),'|','-'),'\','-'),'^','-'),'~','-'),'[','-'),']','-'),';','-')
            ,':','-'),'@','-'),'&','-'),'$','-'),'/','-'),'.','-');
    END

    SET @MyString = LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyString));
    RETURN @MyString
END
```

but as I am replacing the every string with this above function in the query, the query to retrieve the data is slow.

How can I optimize this?

Is there any other way to get the data in quick way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @lad2025 posted is the way to go. That said, in cases where a computed / persisted column is not an option you would benefit from turning you scalar udf into a inline table valued function (itvf). itvf's perform much better than user defined scalar functions (scalar udf) for a number of reasons including the fact that they don't kill parallelism like scalar functions do.

You could rewrite your scalar udf as an itvf like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.itvfReplaceUrlEscapeChars(@MyString as varchar(Max))
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN @MyString LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z\s-]%' 
       THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(
            Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
            Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(
            @MyString,'<','-'),'>','-'),'#','-'),'{','-'),'}','-'),'|','-'),'\','-')
            ,'^','-'),'~','-'),'[','-'),']','-'),';','-'),':','-'),'@','-'),'&','-')
            ,'$','-'),'/','-'),'.','-')))
       ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(@MyString)) 
  END AS cleanedString;
GO
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.GetYearsByMake @Make VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT [year] 
  FROM make_model
  CROSS APPLY dbo.itvfReplaceUrlEscapeChars(make)
  WHERE active=1 AND isUnique=1 
  AND cleanedString = @Make 
  ORDER BY [year] DESC;
END
```

It's also worth noting that working with varchar(max) data types is very expensive. If you can get away with varchar(8000) or less you will see big performance gains as well. Having a filtered nonclustered index on make_model that looked something like this would probably help too:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nc_make_model_poc ON make_model(year)
WHERE active = 1 AND isUnique = 1;
```

Comment: I had search for the cross apply and I found it is same as inner join , so should I start using cross apply instead of inner join between 2 or multiple table too?

Comment: some was down score my question, I think I had made your reply as answer that why another user doesn't like that :-)

Comment: just one more question related to this that what changes we need to make for this query?
SELECT DISTINCT [year] FROM make_model WHERE active=1 AND isUnique=1 AND [dbo].[ReplaceUrlEscapeChars](make)=@Make
  AND [dbo].[ReplaceUrlEscapeChars](model)=@model

Answer (score 0):

Instead of own function and nesting multiple `REPLACE` I would inline [`TRANSLATE - SQL Server 2017+`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[GetYearsByMake] @Make VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT [year] 
  FROM make_model
  WHERE active=1 AND isUnique=1 
    AND TRANSLATE(make, '<>#{}|','------') = @Make 
  ORDER BY [year] DESC;
END
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=05739502491cd44ff52195bec510330e)**

---

Sligthly better approach is to add generated persisted column called `normalized_make` and create and index on top of it.

```
ALTER TABLE make_model
ADD normalized_make AS 
  (CAST(TRIM(TRANSLATE(make, '<>#{}|','------')) AS VARCHAR(100))) PERSISTED;

CREATE INDEX indx_name ON make_model(normalized_make);

SELECT *
FROM make_model
WHERE normalized_make = @Make;
```

---

EDIT:

```
ALTER TABLE make_model
ADD normalized_make AS 
  (CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace
            (Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Make,'<','-'),'>','-'),'#','-'),'{','-'),'}','-'),'|','-'),'\','-'),'^','-'),'~','-'),'[','-'),']','-'),';','-')
            ,':','-'),'@','-'),'&','-'),'$','-'),'/','-'),'.','-'))) AS VARCHAR(100))) PERSISTED;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=279b319f6345cdec8a576698ab6257c5)**

Comment: I am replacing all special character into single -

Comment: @MiteshJain I don't think so, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1498eb1df63017e76114476db95ff3cf Your function will work exactly as I proposed.

Comment: 'TRANSLATE' is not a recognized built-in function name. I am getting error

Comment: using sql server 2014

Comment: TRANSLATE is available from sql server 2017 only @MiteshJain

Comment: @MiteshJain You still can create persisted computed column with nested `REPLACE` and add index on top of it.

Comment: You mean need to create cluster index on that particular column